# Android app crashes when I call bitmap.setPixel

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm tryimng to see if I can creat dynamic images by creating a bitmap and using setPixel.  The program crashes when I call `setPixel`,

```
    Bitmap bm= createBitmap (50,50, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    // program crashes here
    bm.setPixel(25,25,0xffffff);

    // add a test viue
    ImageView mImage= new ImageView(this);
    mImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    layout.addView(mImage);
```

I figure it is something simple, but cannot figure it out.
Ted

Comment: What's the logcat, what's the error, how it crashes?

Comment: add the exception to your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the error message for more information ?

You're using Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, did you have tried with Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 instead ?

Comment: Hi,I tried ARGB_8888 instead, it still crash.  I get a message box that says the application whipe board has stopped unexpedly please try again.